# Powershell AzureML Get-AmlWorkspace

Tags: powershell, azure-machine-learning-service

```
Get-AmlWorkspace : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AmlWorkspace
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AmlWorkspace], 
AggregateException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.AggregateException,AzureML.PowerShell.GetWorkspace
```

I am trying to use Powershell to connect to Azure ML studio as it looks like an easier way to manage a workspace. I've downloaded the dll file from https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps and changed my config.json file, but get the error above if I try to run any AzureML commands. I've unblocked the DLL file and imported the AzureMLPS module, and I can see the module and commands I am trying to use have been imported by doing `Get-Module` and `Get-Command`

For info I've not used Powershell before.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed Azure PowerShell Installer on your local machine?
**[Click here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases)** for more info.

Download the latest **Azure PowerShell Installer (4.3.1)**, then install on your local machine. Then retry using Azure PowerShell module and commands.

I installed mine last May, using Azure PowerShell 4.0.1, and the command Get-AmlWorkspace is working.

```
# Set local folder location
Set-Location -Path "C:\Insert here the location of AzureMLPS.dll"

# Unblock and import Azure Powershell Module (leverages config.json file)
Unblock-File .\AzureMLPS.dll
Import-Module .\AzureMLPS.dll

# Get Azure ML Workspace info
Get-AmlWorkspace
```

The output on my side looks like this:
[image]